# Date column as "YYYYMMDD" string - how to select all rows >= 30 days in the past?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table which contains a `VALID_TO` column as VARCHAR2. This column has date strings in format "YYYYMMDD", e.g. "20160624".

```
ID     ARTICLE_NUMBER   STORE_ID   COUNTRY   VALID_TO
----------------------------------------------------------------
100    111              22         AT        20160624
...
```

What I need is a SELECT that gives me all rows having a `VALID_TO` date that is 30 days old or older. Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? At least your format makes this kind of search simple, but still not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward; find the date 30 days ago, convert it to the same format, and use that for your filter:

```
where valid_to <= to_char(sysdate - 30, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Simple demo using a CTE to generate 40 dates:

```
with t42 (valid_to) as (
  select to_char(trunc(sysdate) - level, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual connect by level <= 40
)
select valid_to
from t42
where valid_to <= to_char(sysdate - 30, 'YYYYMMDD');

VALID_TO
--------
20160525
20160524
20160523
20160522
20160521
20160520
20160519
20160518
20160517
20160516
20160515

 11 rows selected
```

While your stored format makes this kind of search do-able, it's still better to store dates as actual dates rather than as string. There's little stopping you putting an invalid value in there, e.g. 20161357...